# importing customised module using pyproject.toml and setup.cfg in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-import

I have very little experience in making Python packaging. Recently, I have made a module (that was a bit broken in its structure) just using the `setup.py` file. I have to say that the documentation is a bit fragmented and the code shown below is based on little bits that I have gathered from different websites and examples in GitHub.

I have read that now the best way to create modules in Python is using also `pyproject.toml` and `setup.cfg`.

I have created the files and the folder structure of my module (let's call it `dummy`) which looks like this:

```
dummy #this is the project folder
├── README.md
├── LICENSE
├── CHANGELOG.md
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
├── pyproject.toml
└── dummy #actual module with scripts
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── _version.py
    ├── subpackage1
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── script1.py
    ├── subpackage2
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── script2.py
```

My `project.toml` looks like this:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=57.0", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

My `setup.cfg` looks like this:

```
[metadata]
name = dummy
description = Helper functions to make analyses
long_description = file: README.md, CHANGELOG.md, LICENSE
zip_safe = False
license_file = LICENSE
classifiers =
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9

[options]
python_requires = >=3.7
include_package_data = True
install_requires =
    joblib
    mysql.connector
    boto3
    pymongo
    numpy>=1.21.0
    pandas>=1.3.3
    matplotlib
    seaborn
    statsmodels
    merf
    scikit-learn >= 1.0.0
    keras
    tensorflow >= 2.6.0
```

My `setup.py` looks like this:

```
import os.path
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

version_file = os.path.join("dummy", "_version.py")
with open(version_file) as file:
    exec(file.read())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup(
        version=__version__,
        packages=find_packages(include=["dummy", "dummy.*"])
    )
```

The `setup.py` file is getting the version number from `_version.py`, which looks like this:

```
__version__ = "0.2.1"
```

And the `__init__.py` file that is in dummy and at the same level as `_version.py` looks like this:

```
from ._version import __version__

__all__ = ["__version__"]
```

I am using Spyder (Python 3.8, Windows 10) and I set the working directory to where the project folder is. I run the following command: `pip install -e dummy`.

This installs the package without any problems and I can definitely do `import dummy`. However, to access the functions in each submodule (`subpackage1` and `subpackage2`), I need to do this:

```
import dummy.dummy.subpackage1
```

or to get the version of the package I need to do this:

```
import dummy.dummy
dummy.dummy.__version__
```

The package that I made before using only `setup.py` only required this after installation:

```
import dummy.subpackage1
```

I would like to import my module using the syntax above (i.e. using `dummy.subpackage1` and not `dummy.dummy.subpackage1`). My guess is that I am missing some metadata either on `pyproject.toml` or `setup.cfg`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have about 3 different posts here :) probably a dumb question, did you try "pip3 install ." or the modern "python3 -m build" when working in the project directory?

Comment: @chrisinmtown I have managed to make it work eventually with simply "pip install". I still get a warning because of the pip version, so I assume the correct way now is "python3 -m build" in Anaconda prompt?